# eigen matrices multiplication optimizations, Householder precision

Tags: eigen

I develop code performing Schur decomposition.
I test it with eigen corresponding stuff. 
I found out that my code gives result different form those of eigen.
Most of matrix elements of my and egein's output are the same to 2 or 4 decimal places.
However worst difference available is about 70%: for example my code gives certain matrix element equal to 0.3 and eigen 0.19.

I decided to look deeper into eigen sources and figured out that if I change following eigen code

```
void ::applyHouseholderOnTheLeft(....)  
{
  ......
    Map<typename internal::plain_row_type<PlainObject>::type> tmp(workspace,cols());
    Block<Derived, EssentialPart::SizeAtCompileTime, Derived::ColsAtCompileTime> bottom(derived(), 1, 0, rows()-1, cols());
    tmp.noalias() = essential.adjoint() * bottom;
    tmp += this->row(0);
    this->row(0) -= tau * tmp;
    bottom.noalias() -= tau * essential * tmp;
}
```

to this one (same was done for applyHouseholderOnTheRight):

```
void ::applyHouseholderOnTheLeft(....)  
{
  ......
    Map<typename internal::plain_row_type<PlainObject>::type> tmp(workspace,cols());
    Block<Derived, EssentialPart::SizeAtCompileTime, Derived::ColsAtCompileTime> bottom(derived(), 1, 0, rows()-1, cols());
    tmp.noalias() = essential.adjoint() * bottom;
    tmp += this->row(0);
    tmp *= tau;
    this->row(0) -= tmp;
    bottom.noalias() -= essential * tmp;  
}
```

i get eigen output equal to mine (within 7-6 decimal places) !!
Mathematically these two pieces of code are equivalent.
So the question is - why there is so big difference in outputs of equivalent code ?
And what result is actually true (0.3 or 0.19 :-) ) ?

Original test code:

```
      Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> A(10,10); 

        A<<6.9 ,4.8 ,9.5 ,3.1 ,6.5 ,5.8 ,-0.9 ,-7.3 ,-8.1 ,3.0 ,0.1 ,9.9 ,-3.2 ,6.4 ,6.2 ,-7.0 ,5.5 ,-2.2 ,-4.0 ,3.7 ,-3.6 ,9.0 ,-1.4 ,-2.4 ,1.7 ,-6.1 ,-4.2 , -2.5 ,-5.6 ,-0.4 ,0.4 ,9.1 ,-2.1 ,-5.4 ,7.3 ,3.6 ,-1.7 ,-5.7 ,-8.0 ,8.8 ,-3.0 ,-0.5 ,1.1 ,10.0 ,8.0 ,0.8 ,1.0 ,7.5 ,3.5 ,-1.8 ,0.3 ,-0.6 ,-6.3 ,-4.5 , -1.1 ,1.8 ,0.6 ,9.6 ,9.2 ,9.7 ,-2.6 ,4.3 ,-3.4 ,0.0 ,-6.7 ,5.0 ,10.5 ,1.5 ,-7.8 ,-4.1 ,-5.3 ,-5.0 ,2.0 ,-4.4 ,-8.4 ,6.0 ,-9.4 ,-4.8 ,8.2 ,7.8 ,5.2 ,-9.5 , -3.9 ,0.2 ,6.8 ,5.7 ,-8.5 ,-1.9 ,-0.3 ,7.4 ,-8.7 ,7.2 ,1.3 ,6.3 ,-3.7 ,3.9 ,3.3 ,-6.0 ,-9.1 ,5.9; 

    RealSchur<Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor>>schur(A); 

    Matrix<double, Dynamic, Dynamic, RowMajor> T = schur.matrixT();

// and ,for example, element T(row_0, col_2) has notable difference: 0.19 (first code), 0.3 (second code)
```

P.S. vectorization in eigen is disabled in my case (macros EIGEN_DONT_VECTORIZE is defined)

Comment: Can you give an example input matrix where you observe that difference? Without context nobody can say what "the true" result is.

Comment: Please put that example into the question

Comment: And I assume that the Schur decomposition is quite sensitive to small numeric differences (you should still get a valid decomposition but probably with a different order of the blocks)